# How to make an Observable Subject return sync data

Tags: angular, asynchronous, synchronization, observable, subject

I am developing an image file upload code with Angular, with resizing and preview.
The project has an HTML file input to select multiple images. Then, when onload, fire the upload function, resize and preview.
Services upload and resize are called by subscribing.
The issue is when I select several images to upload, the time to process resizing or something else causes an error because the subscribe is getting empty data (or late data...).

```js
  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    // Reset progress bar
    this.progress = 0;
    this.waiting = true;
    const selectedFiles = <FileList>event.srcElement.files;

    // Resize images first
    this.resizeService.resizeImage(selectedFiles, this.maxWidth, this.maxHeight)
    .pipe(
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        // Add property name to obj Blob
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
          data[i].name = selectedFiles[i].name;
        }

        this.resizedFiles = data;
        this.waiting = false;

        // Do upload
        this.onUpload();

        // Reset input file
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    });
  }
```

The resize service:

```js
   

 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class resizeService {

      constructor() { }

      resizeImage(files: FileList, maxWidth: number, maxHeight: number): Observable<any> {
        let resizedFileSubject = new Subject();

        let fileBlobArray: Blob[] = [];

        Array.from(files).map((file, i, { length }) => {
          let image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
          image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

          image.onload = () => {
            let width = image.width;
            let height = image.height;
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            let ctx: any = canvas.getContext("2d");
            let newHeight;
            let newWidth;
            const ratio = width / height;

            // Resize if needed
            if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight) {
              resizedFileSubject.next(file);
            }

            // Calculate aspect ratio
            if (width > height) {
              newWidth = maxHeight * ratio;
              newHeight = maxHeight;
            } else {
              newWidth = maxWidth * ratio;
              newHeight = maxWidth;
            }

            canvas.width = newWidth;
            canvas.height = newHeight;

            // Draw image on canvas
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            fileBlobArray.push(this.b64ToBlob(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")));

            // console.log('push: ', fileBlobArray)

            // Detect end of loop
            if (i + 1 === length) {
              // Wait to get async data - Workaround :(
              // setTimeout(() => {
                resizedFileSubject.next(fileBlobArray);
                // console.log('next: ', fileBlobArray)
              // }, 1000);
            }
          }

        });

        return resizedFileSubject.asObservable();
      }

      /**
      * Convert BASE64 to BLOB
      * @param base64Image Pass Base64 image data to convert into the BLOB
      */
      private b64ToBlob(base64Image: string) {
        const parts = base64Image.split(';base64,');
        const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        const decodedData = window.atob(parts[1]);
        const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(decodedData.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < decodedData.length; ++i) {
          uInt8Array[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: imageType });
      }
    }
```

What I have to do is an workaround by adding a setTimeout of 1s to "wait" until everything is complete (sync an async call??).

The error occurs on here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  data[i].name = selectedFiles[i].name;
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:55)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:35)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at Image.image.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (resize.service.ts:56)
    at Image.wrapFn (zone.js:763)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you passed `selectedFiles` (a list) to `resizeImage()` function. you assumed that you will get a list (with the same size to `selectedFiles`) of resized images in your subscription. but you just `next()` one file in this line:

```
 if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight) {
          resizedFileSubject.next(file);
 }
```

that's why you got the error for `data[i].name` part here:

```
   // Add property name to obj Blob
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      data[i].name = selectedFiles[i].name;
    }
```

I suggest pushing resized or not resized images in a separate array and `next()` the whole array at the end of resizing operation.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Mazdak.

Actually, resizedFileSubject.next(fileBlobArray); is called down below in the end of Array.map() loop.
resizedFileSubject.next(fileBlobArray);

I also added a setTimeout that made the code work, but it is not a good solution.